# Small delay in sudo

Tags: sudo, zsh, performance, real-time

I want my zsh prompt to display whether the session has sudo rights (from a previously run `sudo` command). After looking at the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/553932/how-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-access#553939), I arranged to use the exit status of `sudo -n true` to determine whether the sudo timestamp is still valid.

This works as intended, however the command takes ca. 15 ms to complete. Actually all `sudo` commands seem to have this overhead. This is not much, but I notice it and it bothers me. Given that this is not a computationally expensive operation, is there is a faster way to check this?

Comment: @JeffSchaller How exactly would that work?

Comment: I've run out of ideas; even if `sudo -n true` passed, what if you sat at your prompt long enough for the timestamp to run out? That could be minutes or seconds; I don't have a good solution to this problem.